# Flutter - How to generate validation errors in text fields?

Tags: flutter, dart, validation, controller, textformfield

I'm creating the 'Create Account' page. It contains the following text fields "First Name, Last Name, Email, Password".

**If that field is empty, it will display a validation error above the text form field.**

I tried. But I got only a validated message in the terminal output.

**I want that error displayed in the application.** How to achieve this?

Sample Code:

```
createAccount(){
    productController.createaccount(
      _emailController.text, _passwordController.text, _firstnameController.text, _lastnameController.text,
      );
  }
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 35),
                child: Container(
                  width: 310,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: _firstnameController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      label: RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(
                            text: 'First Name',
                            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                color: Color(0xffc1c1c1),
                                fontSize: 17,
                                letterSpacing: 0.4),
                            children: const [
                              TextSpan(
                                  text: ' *',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                    fontSize: 21,
                                  )),
                            ]),
                      ),
                    ),
                    validator: (value){
                      if(value!.isEmpty){
                        return 'This field is required';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                child: Container(
                  width: 310,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: _emailController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      label: RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(
                            text: 'Enter Your Email',
                            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                color: Color(0xffc1c1c1),
                                fontSize: 17,
                                letterSpacing: 0.4),
                            children: const [
                              TextSpan(
                                  text: ' *',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                    fontSize: 21,
                                  )),
                            ]),
                      ),
                    ),
                    validator: (value){
                      if(value!.isEmpty){
                        return 'This field is required';
                      }
                      if(!RegExp(r'^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$').hasMatch(value)){
                        return 'Enter a valid email';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },

                  ),
                ),
              ),
              
              ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve like this:

**Define your controller and take Globalkey**

```
TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();

  final _loginKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

**Now you need to wrap your Scaffold body to Form widget and define Global key and define autovalidateMode like this:**

```
body: Form(
        key: _loginKey,
        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
child: Column..
```

**That after validate global key on button tap like this::**

```
TextFormField(
              controller: _emailController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                label: RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(text: 'Enter Your Email', children: const [
                    TextSpan(
                        text: ' *',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          fontSize: 21,
                        )),
                  ]),
                ),
              ),
              validator: (value) {
                if (value!.isEmpty) {
                  return 'This field is required';
                }
                if (!RegExp(r'^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$').hasMatch(value)) {
                  return 'Enter a valid email';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),

            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  if (_loginKey.currentState?.validate() == true) {
                    //Navigate to another screen
                  } else {}
                },
                child: Text('Login'))
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It works. But deleting the typed text in the application I got the below error - @pragma("vm:external-name", "AssertionError_throwNew")
  external static _doThrowNew(
      int assertionStart, int assertionEnd, Object? message);
  @pragma("vm:external-name", "AssertionError_throwNewSource")
  external static _doThrowNewSource(
      String failedAssertion, int line, int column, Object? message);  - How to resolve this?

Comment: Divya do you use Column and are you expanding the Column??

Comment: Yes, I'm using the column widget

Comment: Do you wrap Column with Expanded??

Comment: No, I only wrapped it with the center

Comment: Which widgets did you use?? Tabbar etc??

Comment: Feel free me to connect with any problem

Comment: Each text form field is wrapped with a container. And I use center, rich text widgets

Comment: Remove center and try again still error cause??

Comment: Hi Divya if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it] by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution :}

Comment: Removed, it still throws the error.

Comment: Error not causing in my code

Comment: Can you share your code??

Comment: I restarted my application. Now working. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Perfect Divya :}